# Implicit typecasting not working

Tags: c#

I have an abstract class called `Product` and another class called `DifferentProduct` and an interface called `IProduct`.

Both class `Product` and class `DifferentProduct` are derived from an interface called `IProduct`.

```
public class Product : IProduct
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}

public class DifferentProduct : IProduct
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}


public interface IProduct
{
    int ID { get; set; }
}
```

I have function in which I am passing

```
    ProductListing( List<IProduct>, List<IProduct> )
    {

    }
```

Now trying to call function from some file

```
    List<Product> productList1;
    List<DifferentProduct> differentProductList;

    XYZ.ProductListing( productList1, differentProductList );
```

I am getting following errors on above line

> error CS1503 : Argument 1 cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List '
>
> error CS1503 : Argument 2 cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List to
>   System.Collections.Generic.List

Is there any way to work out this solution without explicit typecasting ?
I need to work without explicit typecasting.

Comment: Read about Covariance and Contravariance. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This question is definitely a duplicate of some co/contra variance question

Comment: A list of apples is not a list of fruits. You can add an orange to a list of fruits, but your apple list can't accept that. Your list of DifferentProduct is the same thing. Someone working with a list of Product might expect to be able to add a Widget to your list, but you only gave (or, rather, tried to give) it a list that could accept DifferentProduct.

Comment: Since your method is called `ProductListing`, do you *really* need `IList<T>` as your arguments? Won't `IEnumerable<T>` be enough?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var productList1 = new List<IProduct>();
productList1.Add(new Product());

var differentProductList = new List<IProduct>();
differentProductList.Add(new DifferentProduct)();

XYZ.ProductListing(productList1, differentProductList);
```

You could also do something like this:

```
ProductListing<T, U>(List<T> list1, List<U> list2) where T : IProduct, U : IProduct
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because an `List<Product>` is not a `List<IProduct>`, the same with `List<DifferentProduct>`.

If parameter types in `ProductListing(...)` can be changed to a covariant interface like `IEnumerable<IProduct>` or `IReadOnlyList<IProduct>` then you can pass lists of `Product` or `DifferentProduct` without problems.

Something like this:

```
void ProductListing(IReadOnlyList<IProduct> list1, IReadOnlyList<IProduct> list2)
{
    ...
}
```

Then this is possible:

```
List<Product> productList1;
List<DifferentProduct> differentProductList;

XYZ.ProductListing(productList1, differentProductList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using generics :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        test t = new test();
        List<Product> productList1 = new List<Product>();
        List<DifferentProduct> differentProductList = new List<DifferentProduct>();

        t.ProductListing(productList1, differentProductList);
    }
}

public class test
{
    public void ProductListing<T, U>(List<T> list1, List<U> list2)
        where T : IProduct
        where U : IProduct
    {

    }
}

public abstract class Product : IProduct
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string ProductName{ get; set; }
}

public class DifferentProduct : IProduct
{
  public int ID{get; set;}
}


public interface IProduct
{
    int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: my bad, generic constraints trip me up sometimes. I'd personally make the method parameters be of some covariant interface type instead though, I don't think there's any need for generics here. I find there are very few cases where I actually want a concrete `List<T>` in a method signature.

Comment: I did it this way, because what he wants is to call the ProductListing method with the constraint that the type in the List is an implementation of IProduct interface.